# How to inject a service in a function?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a service `MyService`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LookupsService {
  constructor(private readonly store: Store<never>) {}

}
```

How do I inject it in the following function

```
export function convertToTreeNodes(
  orgs: OrganizationModel[],
  service: LookupsService
): OrganizationNodeInterface[] {
   //...
}
```

I am getting an error saying `Lookup service was not provided`

Thanks for helping

Comment: You can use ` Injector.create` see [this](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)

Comment: If you want working sample please put the code in stacklibtz.

Comment: "Best practice" is to inject the service into the class constructor, then save a reference to it as a class member.  Like your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services can only be injected in something of which lifecycle is maintained by Angular.  A normal function exported doesn't have a lifecycle so angular can't inject any dependencies.
You have couple of options:

1. convert this function to a service and inject the lookup service. I would prefer this option as its clean.
2. Second option is probably save away an instance of injector in a locator service inside app module constructor and use it later to get services. e.g.

```
    // app.module
    export class AppModule {
      constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        ServiceLocator.init(injector);
      }
    }
    
    // blah.ts
    export function blah() {
      ServiceLocator.get(LookupsService)
    }
    
    
    //service-locator.ts
    export class ServiceLocator {
      private injector: Injector;
      init(injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
      }
      get(klass) {
        return this.injector.get(klass);
      }
    }
```